# search function causes program to crash

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, tree, logic

I have been going through the debugger but can't seem to pinpoint exactly what is going wrong. I have come to my own conclusion i must be missing a nullptr check somewhere or something. If anyone can provide some help it would be greatly appreciated.

**error message from debugger**

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOFcO.png)

which looks like makes the program crash on this line:

```
if (node->children_[index] == nullptr) {
```

**search function**

```
    Node* search(const string& word, Node* node, int index) const {
            Node* temp;
            //same as recurssive lookup just difference is returns node weather terminal or not
            if (index < word.length()) {


                            index = node->getIndex(word[index]);


                            if (node->children_[index] == nullptr) {
                                    return nullptr;
                            }
                            else {
                                    temp = search(word, node->children_[index], index++);
                            }
                    }

                    return temp; // this would give you ending node of partialWord


            }
```

**Node struct for reference**

```
    struct Node {
            bool isTerminal_;
            char ch_;
            Node* children_[26];
            Node(char c = '\0') {
                    isTerminal_ = false;
                    ch_ = c;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                            children_[i] = nullptr;
                    }
            }
            //given lower case alphabetic charachters ch, returns 
            //the associated index 'a' --> 0, 'b' --> 1...'z' --> 25
            int getIndex(char ch) {
                    return ch - 'a';

            }
    };
    Node* root_;


int suggest(const string& partialWord, string suggestions[]) const {

    Node* temp;

    temp = search(partialWord, root_, 0);

    int count = 0;
    suggest(partialWord, temp, suggestions, count);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Press "Break" and examine the variables in the debugger.

Comment: At some point in your recursion null is almost certainly passed as `node`. The layout  of your struct suggests `children` is at base+4, and the actual fault comes from attempting to read at location `0x00000004`.  The debugger broke on `node->children[...]`. So your assessment of missing a null-check somewhere is possible.

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue but in the recursive call `search(word, node->children_[index], index++)` the order of evaluation of `node->children_[index]` and `index++` is unspecified. Pass `index` and increment afterwards if that's what you mean.

Comment: @molbdnilo I would almost bank on that being the issue.

Comment: @ molbdnilo i used your suggestion and incremented index outside of that paramater. The crash does not happen when i do this, but the return value of the index is 0 when it should be something such as 15

Comment: The way you use `index` to represent both an index in the word and an index of a child node is very confusing, and very likely involved in the issue. Use separate variables for separate things.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are very correct. How would i go about incrementing the variable properly? i put it oustide of the recurssive call but it gives me the wrong int returned inside the function call

Answer (score 0):

Might be a very simple thing.  Without digging I am not sure about the rank of the `->` operator versus the `==` operator.  I would take a second and try putting parenthesis around the "`node->children_[index] == nullptr`" part like this:

```
(node->children_[index]) == nullptr
```

just to make sure that the logic runs like you seem to intend.

Dr t

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) assumptions in the OP's code.Both `->` and `[]` will take precedence over `==`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root cause is that you're using `index` for two distinct purposes: as an index into the word you're looking for, and as an index into the node's children.
When you get to the recursion, `index` has changed meaning, and it's all downhill from there.

You're also passing `index++` to the recursion, but the value of `index++` is the value it had before the increment.
You should pass `index + 1`.

[An issue in a different program would be that the order of evaluation of function  parameters is unspecified, and you should never both modify a variable and use it in the same parameter list. (I would go so far as to say that you should never modify *anything* in a parameter list, but many disagree.)
But you shouldn't use the same variable here at all, so...]

I would personally restructure the code a little, something like this:

```
Node* search(const string& word, Node* node, int index) const {
    // Return immediately on failure.
    if (index >= word.length())
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    int child_index = node->getIndex(word[index]);

    // The two interesting cases: we either have this child or we don't.
    if (node->children_[child_index] == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        return search(word, node->children_[child_index], index + 1);
    }
}
```

(Side note: returning a pointer to a non-const internal `Node` from a `const` function is questionable.)